# How change this date format "2020-04-30T18:11:39+00:00" to IST format in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, datetime-format

Hi I am stuck in converting this date format "2020-04-30T18:11:39+00:00" into IST datetime format.

```
declare @fiveandhalf datetime = '05:30'
print(@fiveandhalf)

declare @datetime datetime = (SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '2020-04-30 18:11:39'))

print(@datetime-@fiveandhalf)
```

I am getting this output

```
Apr 30 2020 12:41PM
```

but I need output like "2020-04-30 23:41: "

Comment: Where did you get stuck? Show use your attempts. Why isn't it working? Date and Time data types don't have a "format", they are binary values; what you need to do isn't "change the format" it's change the time zone.

Comment: In the database, assuming the right data types are being used (`datetime2`, for example), it doesn't *have* a format. Leave formatting to the last possible moment in the application, not down in the database.

Comment: Hi, I have edited the question again please have a look

Answer (score 1):

***Assuming*** you are using the appropriate data type for a value with a timezone component, a `datetimeoffset`, just use `AT TIME ZONE`:

```sql
DECLARE @YourDate datetimeoffset(0) = '2020-04-30T18:11:39+00:00';

SELECT @YourDate AT TIME ZONE 'India Standard Time';
```

Which returns the `datetimeoffset` value `2020-04-30 23:41:39 +05:30`.

Comment: "Assuming you are using the appropriate data type for a value with a timezone component". Even if you're not, fake it until you make it. A trick I often use is: `select @dt at time zone 'UTC' at time zone 'Pacific Standard Time';`. Which is to say that you can tell SQL Server what TZ the unadorned datetime-ish value is in at which point you can apply TZ conversions to *that*.